# Random variable counting 2 success in $n$ trials

Tags: probability

I have this exercise :

> One leads a sequence of Bernoulli experiences with $0 < p < 1$. Let $X$ be the r.v. counting the number of experiences (successful or not) performed until $2$ experiences (consecutive or not) are successful. Determinate $\mathbb{P}(X=n)$ for any integer $n ≥ 2$. Note that at least two experiences are needed to have two successes.

I've done this

$S_X = \{2, \dots, \}$. So we need two success : this happen with probability $p^2$ and we need $n-2$ failures, which happens with probability $(1-p)^{n-2}$. So, for me, $\mathbb{P}(X = n) = p^2 (1-p)^{n-2}$, which is a wrong answer. But my reasoning is correct for me, so where is the error ?

Any help is welcome, thanks

Comment: For $n>1$, one happens at the $n$-th time, and the other one happens among the first $n-1$ times, so the prob is simply $(n-1)p^2(1-p)^{n-2}$

Comment: Your calculation gives the probability of $n-2$ consecutive failures followed by $2$ successes. However there are more possibilities. E.g. first a success, then $n-2$ consecutive failures and then a second success. Btw, note that this possibility has again the probability that you already calculated. Make use of that to find the correct solution.

Comment: Have a look at [negative binomial distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution).